# Chromium doesn't play sound

Tags: sound, chromium

I have Chromium installed on Ubuntu 13.04, but aside from flash things, it seems I can't get a sound out of it.

For instance, I installed an extension, [SpeakIt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speakit/pgeolalilifpodheeocdmbhehgnkkbak?hl=en), which is supposed to read paragraphs aloud, but I get no sound out of it. The test includes listening to an audio file, I don't get anything out of that either.

I *do* hear sounds when played by YouTube, which makes me believe that the computer's sound itself isn't a problem, only Chromium's (because Flash makes sounds).

I *don't* hear sounds the browser plays (like Google Translate's speak).

What can I do to troubleshoot? What could be the problem?

When looking in the **Sound > Applications** submenu, it doesn't even show up there. When I play a YouTube video, it does show.

[image]

<sub>Example of what happens when YouTube video is playing</sub>

Comment: If you guys need more information about the problem, don't be shy and comment me about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's a simpler way to fix it: `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`. Source: [Bug #991758](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/991758)

Comment: That's the correct answer in my opinion. No need to fuss around with the files manually.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. This is an old bug about Chromium: [Issue 22152: <audio> tag doesn't work for extension resources](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22152). Anyway, I didn't understand how they fixed there (actually I have not bothered myself) - if they fixed (is written that it is fixed). Because of that I won't explain what is happening there.

I fixed it by following the following steps:

- [Download and install Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en).
- Replace `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpegsumo.so` file with `/opt/google/chrome/libffmpegsumo.so` (preventive, you can make a copy of the original file).

[image: Replace libffmpegsumo.so]

- Optional, uninstall Google Chrome if you don't need anymore or if you don't intend to use it in the future.
- Open Chromium browser and check if you can hear sounds now, in Google Translations for example.

[image: Check if sound is working]

---

I think, not sure, that this happens because many of the audio and video codecs included in Chrome aren't included in Chromium due to licensing, patents and stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

No need for install, just download the package and extract, like:

```
sudo dpkg -x google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ./google
sudo cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpegsumo.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpegsumo.so.backup
sudo cp /home/YOURUSERNAME/Downloads/google/opt/google/chrome/libffmpegsumo.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpegsumo.so
```

Ok, restart chromium.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this if you have downloaded chromium from Ubuntu Software.**

The same problem will occur in this case also.

To fix this follow these steps.

1. Go to Ubuntu Software > Installed > look for Chromium browser

   [image: Chromium page for details]

   Click on *Permission* tab
2. Look at opened window

   [image: Enable play audio in window]

   Enable  *Play audio*