# No sound on chrome (Only) after using an HDMI cable

Tags: sound, google-chrome, hdmi

I used a hdmi cable to broadcast some youtube content to my tv (using chrome). I had to change the sound output from "speakers" to "hdmi" to have it on the tv.

Now, there is no sound on my computer only when I use chrome, and in the output choices I only have "speakers". And even when I put some sound on chrome and I go to sound settings -> application, I find that chrome is unmuted and the sound is detected, but still there is no sound for me.
How can I fix it ?

I tried deleting the config directory of chrome, re-installing chrome and many solutions found on the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: It happens only in youtube? ie: have you tried to play mp3 files? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video it could the flash plugin. http://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10

Comment: it is the whole chrome, not only youtube. I am sure the outpur of chrome is still the hdmi cable, but as it is not plugged i cannot see it in the sound settings.  I don't find the way to change the configuration.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same problem. When I changed sound output device to HDMI, I did it in PulseAudio Volume Control. This made the sound in Chrome disappear. To fix it:

1. Open PulseAudio Volume Control (open a terminal and type `pavucontrol`)
2. Go to the Configuration tab and identify the drop-down list that contains HDMI outputs. Set that profile to *Off*.
3. Select profile for the drop-down list that contains your normal sound output (e.g. *Analog Stereo Output*).

Comment: Also works on Debian, I just had to install it first.

Comment: Also work for me to fix problem with USB headphones.

Comment: I didn't have sound in both Chrome and Firefox on 16.04 and this hack fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had audio on vlc but not on anything else.. and my hdmi to tv didn't show any more in sound setting

ubuntu 16.04

install and switched and now i got audio again