# Sound not working anymore after unplugging HDMI cable

Tags: 18.04, sound, hdmi

I recently experienced a weird behaviour of the sound system on my laptop.

I connect my laptop via HDMI on a TV and choose to use the sound system of the TV in `Parameters > Sound`. Then I unplug the HDMI cable and I am unable to listen to anything on my computer.

To get the sound back on the laptop I have to connect my laptop the TV again and choose to use the internal sound system. And then only unplug the computer.

Is there a way to switch to the internal sound system without having to perform the previous procedure ?

EDIT : What I tried from kenn's comment :

```bsh
pactl set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

Which seems to be the root of all the solutions I've been linked too. But unfortunately I still can't play a music or a video in my browser or outside.
Note : The sound from the system are working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HDMI sound output automatically on connect/disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263248/set-hdmi-sound-output-automatically-on-connect-disconnect)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/458194/switching-to-hdmi-audio-when-hdmi-is-plugged-into-a-laptop-14-04

Comment: Thank your for the help, I tried to use the answer given in your links but it is still not working, see my edit.

Comment: I stumbled across https://askubuntu.com/a/660457/974073 in the Related section. It has solved my problem. Not sure what to do now with this question which seems to be a duplicate of both the links you provided and the answer given in this comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No sound on chrome (Only) after using an HDMI cable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659499/no-sound-on-chrome-only-after-using-an-hdmi-cable) **Close Voters** OP pointed this as duplicate that fixes problem.