# No sound in Chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome

I have sound using opera and firefox. The flashplayer is enabled, but when I wanna play youtube videos or videos posted on youtube, google chrome is silent. Why is this?

Might be the flash player:[image]

UPDATE: I was wrong...chromium wont work either...so, that cant be an alternative solution either.

Shall I just use this command: sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer and disable the pepperflash of google chrome? Would that be a way to solve this?

Comment: When playing a video check in **Sound Settings** > **Applications** tab if Chrome is not muted ?

Comment: @hg8 of course it is not muted.:)

Comment: Haha starting from the beginning just to be sure sorry :)

Comment: @hg8 no worries. normal. Weird though.....I think it might have to do something with the flashplayer. It is enabled. I just dont know why it is adobe flashplayer (check screenshot of the OP)...when for chrome it should be pepper, right? I might go back to chromium.

Comment: nah....same issue. I am using Opera for now and it works just fine. This has been like this for months, but now that I have a new laptop, I wanna find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried that : http://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10?answertab=votes#tab-top ?

Comment: @hg8 I havent. I dont wanna use just any random commands to do stuff that might mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:
(but your issue may be different)
* Install [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/pavucontrol/)
* Open pavucontrol
* In the playback tab you should see chrom[e|ium] as sound souce
* In the (unlabeled) destination dropdown button change sound destination. (In my case from "internal digital" to "interlan analog" fixed the problem.)

(Unsolved: How to make this stick after reboot.)