# Ubuntu 15.04 Google Chrome 45.0.2454.93 No sound

Tags: sound, 15.04, google-chrome, browser

When using Google Chrome there is no sound (youtube, vimeo, facebook, flash and etc.)

In Mozilla the sound is working as it should!

Comment: Are you using pulse audio?

Comment: I am using whatever came with Ubuntu 15.04, haven't installed anything special for sound...

Comment: What does this command say??           "aplay -l"

Comment: Also tell me what does this command say? "pactl list"

Comment: Hmm, it's too long to paste here, anyways the problem is solved! Thanks

Comment: This solution on another thread helped for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/668329/540381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do this to restart `alsa` and `pulseaudio` (`pulseaudio` auto-restarts):

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

If that doesn'work try to reinstall alsa and pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base && sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

Comment: For the first one I got an error stating that alsa is not a command.

Second one did the magic (after restart), thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `pavucontrol`.
2. Check the application and the output device, select the correct and check again.