# No sound after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound

So I recently upgraded to 18.04 and now I have no sound. I've read through and tried various solution on this site and nothing is working so far.

[image: sound settings]

[image: volume control]

[image: alsamixer]

Comment: Please say *what* you have tried, otherwise we are likely to make the same suggestions. Please add hardware information such as the make & model of your device

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

Comment: I've tried the pulseaudio kill cmd as well

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039012/sound-problem-in-firefox-after-upgrade-to-18-04

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also a problem, because there was no error. I tried to find and apply many solutions but without success.

The final solution was simple: remove the headphones... Try it.

Comment: Remove the headphones? I assume you're talking about in the alsamixer?