# Sound coming from Chrome not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, google-chrome, 22.10

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10, but now I discover that the sound coming from Google Chrome is not working, whilst it is working when coming from other applications, such as Spotify or Videos.
I have already tried these two solutions:
[No sound from Chrome, sound works fine in Firefox etc (13.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/takelessons/takelessons-classroom/additional-troubleshooting/ubuntu--linux-sound-issues-in-chrome

But it still doesn't work.
Please help me and thank you in advance.
Hans

Comment: does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/457978/no-sound-from-chrome-sound-works-fine-in-firefox-etc-13-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Not really, it shows up but it still won't play any sound